# Quotient of cohomology groups with different coefficents

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, (if necessary I'm ok with assuming that $M$ is four dimensional, orientable, and closed). I wish to understand the quotient:
$$Q=H^1(M;\mathbb{R})/H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})$$
I have seen this pop up in a paper I am reading on Seiberg-Witten theory but I unfortunately don't really understand how to make sense of this space. Particularly, I am not sure I fully understand how to realize $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ as a subgroup of $H^1(M;\mathbb{R})$, since I am unsure of how to relate their two constructions (i.e. as homomorphism groups from chains to the reals/integers). I believe that I am perhaps missing something naive, as my algebraic topology is definitely lack luster. If anyone could provide any insight I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Do you understand the relation between the real and integer chains? How about real and integer cocycles?

Comment: @MoisheKohan is there a relationship other than the fact that we can (I believe at least) embed integers chains into real chains?

Comment: You only believe or you can prove it? Try to prove it. Then try cochains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal coefficients gives, for any abelian group $A$ and any $X$, an isomorphism

$$H^1(X, A) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(X), A)$$

(since $H_0(X)$ is free, so the Ext term vanishes). If in addition $H_1(X)$ is finitely generated (which is always true if $X$ is a closed manifold), write $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \oplus T$ where $T$ is the torsion subgroup. Since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are both torsion-free we have

$$H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^r, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^r$$

and similarly

$$H^1(X, \mathbb{R}) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(X), \mathbb{R}) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^r, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^r.$$

Moreover the universal coefficients isomorphism is natural in $A$, which implies that the coefficient map $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \hookrightarrow H^1(X, \mathbb{R})$ is the obvious inclusion $\mathbb{Z}^r \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^r$. So their quotient is a torus $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^r$.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Quick aside, does this imply that if $M$ is a closed manifold, that it’s integral cohomology can’t have torsion?

Comment: @Chris: no, only for $H^1$ does the Ext term of universal coefficients always vanish like this. In general if all of the homology groups are finitely generated then universal coefficients implies that the same is true of the cohomology groups; moreover $H^i$ has the same rank as $H_i$ but the torsion is shifted up one degree, so that the torsion in $H_i$ is isomorphic to the torsion in $H^{i+1}$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I am struggling to see how we conclude that the coefficient map $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})\hookrightarrow H^1(X,\mathbb R)$ is the obvious one. Everything I see about the universal coefficients theorem states that it is not natural

Comment: @Chris: the universal coefficient exact sequence itself is natural. It's the splitting that isn't natural. But since the Ext term vanishes here anyway that doesn't matter.

Comment: In this context what does natural mean? Like if $A$ is some arbitrary abelian group, there are many morphisms $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ given by choosing where $1$ goes. So how do we know what morphism corresponds to the isomorphism in universal coefficients theorem?

Comment: @Chris: natural means that every term in the universal coefficient theorem is a functor and every morphism in the universal coefficient theorem is a natural transformation between functors. When someone writes $H^1(M, \mathbb{R})/H^1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ they are using a specific map $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(M, \mathbb{R})$ to make sense of this quotient, and that map is the map functorially induced by the usual inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is a (very standard) convention.

Comment: Let $\iota:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the inclusion, this induces a map on singular cochains given by $\omega\mapsto \iota\circ \omega$, which commutes with the differential so defines a map on cohomology $[\omega]\mapsto[\iota\circ \omega]$. How do I see that this map is the same as the map $\mathbb{Z}^r\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^r$?

Comment: @Chris: like I said, it follows from universal coefficients that this map is the same as the map $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^r, \mathbb{Z}) \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^r, \mathbb{R})$ given by applying the functor $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^r, -)$.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense thank you.